# Circle masking for pool balls using shaders

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, mask

In a 2D pool game using OpenGL ES 2.0, I need to mask the "white" and "number" textures as they rotate around the edges of the balls. I currently have it working with stencils, but there are two issues:

1. No anti-aliasing on the stencil test, making jagged edges.
2. Each ball is separately masked (adjacent balls could otherwise bleed into one another), and it's too slow to clear and recreate the stencil buffer multiple times per frame.

I'm pretty sure the best solutions would involve shader code, but I'm new to shader programming (and pretty new to OpenGL itself), and the volume of results I've uncovered in research left me unsure how best to proceed.

This one seems close to what I need:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98573/how-do-i-draw-a-circular-portion-of-a-texture-within-libgdx-using-an-opengl-es-s

In particular, the first answer "Alpha mask texture" approach, using a gray-scale image as the alpha value for the final gl_FragColor. But I couldn't find any examples of how to set up a shader program like that. (Common examples had 3 images with background, foreground, and mask, and used mix() to blend them).

For example, the mask would be the size and shape of the whole ball, but textures like the numbers are drawn on a portion of the ball (and with a different transform matrix for the perspective), so the texture coordinates would be completely different for image and mask. And I couldn't find anything similar to that.

A second alternative that is likely much easier, would be just using 'discard' for pixels beyond some distance^2 from the center. Might even be able to feather the alpha. I found this approach:
https://gist.github.com/tgfrerer/6009069

...but it uses features not available in ES 2.0. If someone could provide an example similar in functionality but suitable for ES, that would also be welcome. As would contrasting the merits of either approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this paper can help: https://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf
I think it is exactly what you need - and should work fine in ES2.

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I didn't understand how the "magnification for vector textures" process relates to or helps solve the masking scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution now using the second 'distance' method. And since it's also doing smooth edges, I should be good to go. Note that the uniforms for center and inner/outerEdge all need to be in "window coordinates". The per-pixel sqrt in distance() bothers me a bit, but I tried unrolling it into a distance^2 test, and that profiled even slower.

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float innerEdge;
uniform float outerEdge;
uniform float alpha;
uniform sampler2D s_texture;
void main() {
  float dist = distance(gl_FragCoord.xy, center);
  if (dist >= innerEdge)
    gl_FragColor = alpha * (1. - smoothstep(innerEdge, outerEdge, dist)) * texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);
  else
    gl_FragColor = alpha * texture2D(s_texture, v_texCoord);
}
```